# Which one is first initiate in MVC framework?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, controller

I think Model first initiate in MVC Framework. because we only add the functionality (like calling models) in controller after that view is called. Please let me know if anybody knows

Comment: Request goes to a controller method. Controller method returns a view and it's model. View use model to render data on it's ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a controller or Model because

**Reason why its controller**

Because when we run the URL.The Url first reach to a controller.After coming to the controller it goes to model or view.So controller run first and model and view.

**Reason why its Model**

It is simple to think at first we need to config the DB first so do run's first and controller.i think it is not :)

I'm concluding that controller is first then model and model queries goes to view.